# Custom SQL query with custom taxonomies (Wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I use the following SQL query to fetch custom posts in Wordpress. 
I ended up with this solution because i needed to fetch und sort the posts based on custom meta data. This woks pretty well so far!

But how do i incorporate custom taxonomies in my query?
Say for example only fetch posts that are associated with term_id 5?
I'm really stuck here cause i can't figure out how wp_terms, relations etc are connected...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
After some reading the solution in my case is this:

WordPress stores the relations between taxonomies and posts in `wp_term_relationships` (where `object_id` is the `post_id` and `term_taxonomy_id` ist the `term_id` in `wp_terms`). So if i want to only fetch posts that belong to a specific term_id, i came up with the following query. Seems to work as far as i can tell!

This is my query

```
global $wpdb;
$activelang = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
$cmonth = date('Y-m');

$myquery = "
SELECT wposts.*, wpostmeta.meta_value AS date
  FROM wp_posts wposts, wp_postmeta wpostmeta, wp_icl_translations wicl_translations, , wp_term_relationships wptermrelations
  WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND wpostmeta.post_id = wposts.ID
  AND (wptermrelations.object_id = wposts.ID AND (wptermrelations.term_taxonomy_id = '29' OR wptermrelations.term_taxonomy_id = '30'))
  AND wposts.post_type = 'event'
  AND wicl_translations.element_id = wposts.ID
  AND wicl_translations.language_code = '$activelang'
  AND (wpostmeta.meta_key = '_ws_prem_date' OR wpostmeta.meta_key = '_ws_date1_date' OR ... ... OR wpostmeta.meta_key = '_ws_date10_date') 
  AND wpostmeta.meta_value >= '$cmonth-01'
  ORDER BY CAST(date AS DATETIME),wposts.post_title ASC
  ";

$myloop = $wpdb->get_results($myquery);
```

In case someone is wondering what this query does:

This query fetches custom post types (events that have multiple dates associated) and builds a loop for these events that allows for duplicate entries since a 'normal' WordPress loop always filters out any duplicate entries.

Comment: Either use a series of OUTER JOINs for each of the term criteria (faster) or create a psuedo-normalized pivot from the data set (easier to read). These solutions are discussed elsewhere (frequently in connection with wordpress queries) but if you need further help consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: thanks Strawberry! I did not know of sqlfiddle, will report back if i have a working fiddle.